# Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a041f': Unexpected 'Next'

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm trying to program a multiplayer tic-tac-toe game in VBScript/ASP.

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a041f': Unexpected 'Next'

Here's the code on which the error above occurs:

```
For x = 1 To 3
 If AllEqual(arr(x,1),  arr(x,1), arr(x,1)) Then
  If arr(x,1) = GetText(currentplayer) Then
   bWinner = currentplayer
  Else If arr(x,1) = GetText(0) Then
   'nothing to do
  Else
   If GetNumber(arr(x,1)) <> currentplayer Then
    bWinner = GetNumber(arr(x,1))
   End If
  End If 
 End If
Next
```

And here's the output of the error message:

> /iTicTic/play.asp, line 82
>
> ```
> Next
> ^
> ```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: full code here: http://pastebin.com/BcR4HZ4a

Comment: Is this all of the file?

Comment: If you came here trying to use `Next` inside the loop: there is no `continue` in VBScript. It’ll only yield a 800A041F.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe it's due to the use of `Else If`, the proper syntax is `ElseIf`. Basically with `Else If` it is seeing that as a new `If` statement that would need it's own closing `End If` statement.